# datatypes porting a c++ code to Linux from win32

Tags: c++, linux, winapi

I have a **c++** code written using win32. In terms of data types it uses:

1. primitives (`int, double, float, bool, long`,...)
2. Windows data types (`INT, SHORT, LONG, BOOL, BYTE, WCHAR`,...)
3. and a couple of other data types: `__int64` and `wchar_t`

**Questions:**

i. to port this code to **Linux**, what data types should I use ?

ii. alternatively, to make it **cross platform** (Linux and win32), are these data types different from that in (i) ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the data types provided by the language, of course. These are fundamental data types, like `char` and `int`. Beyond that, use `int8_t`, `int16_t`, ... and so on, defined in the `<cstdint>` header.

Be careful when it comes to `BOOL` though, if I remember correctly, there are some parts of Windows that define `BOOL` as `char`, while others use `int`. And I think that there are even some places where values other than `TRUE` and `FALSE` (resp. `1` and `0`) are used with data type `BOOL`.

Thus, naively changing every `BOOL` to `bool` and every `WCHAR` to `wchar_t` can lead to surprises when it comes to overload resolution and even break your code in tremendous ways if these types are used for serialization.

Another thing that comes to my mind is Window's way to handle ASCII/Unicode with all these `TCHAR`s that may either end up as `CHAR` or `WCHAR`, depending on your preprocessor defines, so you need to decide how to transfer these.

---

Some general advice:

Do NOT misuse types. For example, do not define your variables, arguments and return types as `int` if they store stuff like handles or pointers (e.g. `HINSTANCE`, `HWND`, and these sorts of things). Instead define a meaningful type for that, e.g.

```
using native_handle_t = HINSTANCE;
```

It is then easy to provide an alternative define for linux or other platforms and there is no need to search and change your entire code base.

When it comes to serialization, e.g. writing to binary files, you should stick to fixed-sized types (`uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, ...), since they are of the right size on every platform. Sending network packets with `long`s on a platform where the size of `long` is `4` and reading them on a platform where `long`'s size is `8` isn't necessarily a good thing!

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating on [nh_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46076302/3501)s answer about `BOOL`.

Windows has [3 Boolean types](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041222-00/?p=36923):

- `BOOL` is a 32-bit type. The `TRUE` and `FALSE` defines specify the basic values but most APIs returning `BOOL` are documented to return non-zero on success so you should just write `BOOL succ = somefunc(); if (succ) {...}`.
- `BOOLEAN` is a 8-bit type. Mostly used by the Window NT kernel and NT API but has leaked into Win32 in various places over the years.
- `VARIANT_BOOL` is a 16-bit type used in COM/Automation. `VARIANT_FALSE` is 0 and `VARIANT_TRUE` is actually -1 (`0xffff`)!

Because of how `VARIANT_BOOL` is defined and how `BOOL` is used you should only test if something is false (compare with 0) or use `if (x)` and/or `if (!x)` style expressions...

Comment: Great addition to my answer. Thank you!